# Add multiple static IP's for a client in ISC dhcpd4

Tags: networking, dhcp-server

Currently I'm migrating the network from static IP addresses client-side to a static IP pool in a central DHCP server. Some of my clients have multiple network interfaces, which I'd each like to assign IP addresses for.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to add the host twice in this kind of fashion, because dhcpd4 then starts to complain about duplicate hosts:

`host compaq {
        # Internal Intel card
        option host-name "compaq.lan";
        hardware ethernet aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff;
        fixed-address 192.168.10.55;
 }
 host compaq {
        # External Ralink card
        option host-name "compaq.lan";
        hardware ethernet 00:11:22:33:44:55;
        fixed-address 192.168.10.55;
 }`

Is it possible to add static IP's for multiple NIC's on a single client otherwise, and how so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unique `host{}` block names. They are not relevant to the dHCP protocol itself, so you can safely name them like "compaq_intel" or "compaq_eth0".

(Meanwhile, dhcpd won't complain about duplicate IP addresses, but is that really what you want?)